# Redshift Federated Query error: timeout expired code: 2500

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, federated-queries

After having created a 'Federated Schema' to access a remote RDS instance (different AWS account but [VPC Peered](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/create-vpc-peering-connection.html)):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA federated_schema
FROM POSTGRES
DATABASE 'popstgres_db' SCHEMA 'public'
URI 'my.host.com'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::1223456789:role/MyRole'
SECRET_ARN 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:my-region-1:1223456789:secret:my/secret';
```

I try to test it with a simple Federated Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM federated_schema.my_table
```

But after some waiting I get the following error message:

`error: timeout expired code: 2500`

The error message doesn't really help as I already checked there is connection between the relative 2 VPCs hosting the relative services.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in this Enhanced VPC document https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-enhanced-vpc-routing/

> To determine whether you should enable Amazon Redshift enhanced VPC routing, consider the following use cases:

> [...]Federated queries to private Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) instances located in a peered VPC.

So it is necessary to enable Enhanced VPC Routing on your Redshift Cluster:

from Console → Clusters → my-dwh → Properties → Network and security settings → Edit → Enhanced VPC routing)

After enabling it the Federated Query started working